# Reading in 'messy' looking XML file into R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I am trying to get an XML file into R as a data frame that I can easily handle. I have gone through examples online easily enough, but I can't find an example with a format similar to my XML file. It's from the [US Treasury website](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldYear&year=2005).

Here is the URL to the specific XML file:

http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202005

I would like to get a dataframe which looks like the table on the website (columns of date, 1mo, 3mo, 6mo,...).The following code is running but not giving me the desired result. I suspect it is because the XML file is more complex than the examples I have been looking at.

```
Ad<-'http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202005'
XML <- xmlTreeParse(Ad)
xmltop <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
XMLcat <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
plantcat_df <- data.frame(t(XMLcat),row.names=NULL)
```

Nor is

```
Data <- xmlToDataFrame(xml.url)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shld read up on namespaces in XML and how they work in R and also XPath in general. Also, `xml2` is a newer XML pkg and has some nice features you should look into.

```
library(xml2)

# read the doc
doc <- read_xml("http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202005")

# libxml2 + R == "meh" handling of default namespaces
ns <- xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(doc), d1="default")

# all the info is in the properties tag so focus on it
props <- xml_find_all(doc, "//default:entry/default:content/m:properties", ns)

# lots of ways to extract, but this data is "regular" enough to take a
# rather simplistic approach. Extract all the node values which will be 
# separated by newlines. Convert newlines to tabs, trim the whole thing
# and read it in as a table.
dat <- read.table(text=trimws(gsub("\n", "\t", unlist(lapply(props, xml_text)))), 
                  sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# column names wld be good so build those from one property node
colnames(dat) <- xml_name(xml_children(props[[1]]))

# boom: done
str(dat)
## 'data.frame': 250 obs. of  14 variables:
##  $ Id              : int  3040 3041 3042 3043 3044 3045 3046 3047 3048 3049 ...
##  $ NEW_DATE        : chr  "        2005-11-14T00:00:00" "        2005-11-10T00:00:00" "        2005-11-15T00:00:00" "        2005-11-17T00:00:00" ...
##  $ BC_1MONTH       : num  3.93 3.89 4.01 3.98 4 ...
##  $ BC_3MONTH       : num  4.02 3.97 4.01 4.01 4 ...
##  $ BC_6MONTH       : num  4.35 4.3 4.34 4.3 4.3 ...
##  $ BC_1YEAR        : num  4.4 4.34 4.38 4.32 4.34 ...
##  $ BC_2YEAR        : num  4.5 4.44 4.47 4.37 4.42 ...
##  $ BC_3YEAR        : num  4.52 4.48 4.5 4.39 4.43 ...
##  $ BC_5YEAR        : num  4.54 4.49 4.51 4.39 4.43 ...
##  $ BC_7YEAR        : num  4.57 4.51 4.52 4.42 4.45 ...
##  $ BC_10YEAR       : num  4.61 4.55 4.56 4.46 4.49 ...
##  $ BC_20YEAR       : num  4.9 4.85 4.83 4.75 4.77 ...
##  $ BC_30YEAR       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ BC_30YEARDISPLAY: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```